# How to recover from thin content ranking drops (no manual action)?

Tags: seo, google, penalty, thin-content

Overnight I lost about 90% of my website's organic traffic without receiving a manual action. I'm pretty sure this was because of adding a lot of thin content which I forgot to add 'noindex' to.

Is there any way to recover from this? I've added noindex meta to all my thin content pages but it doesn't seem to be helping. Do you think I should just drop this site and start a new one?

Comment: ***Do you think I should just drop this site and start a new one?*** Heck no! How long has it been? Search is *not* real-time. It can take weeks or months depending upon how often Google crawls your site. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to hear about the drop in traffic OP. Here's a few things I would look into to start off with:

- Be patient. Nothing about organic changes quickly
- I would check to see *which pages* traffic dropped off from
- Look up your category of site and see if it falls under any recent
  updates
- Check your top competitors (or similar sites) to see if they had a similar drop in traffic using 3rd party tools
- If you know there's no manual action, you must have it verified in search console. Check query and page performance there.

  - Check coverage report. Look for errors, look in **excluded** tab
- Check backlinks, linking domains
- Double check robots.txt and indexing directives. Too often I see full sites with **`disallow: /`** blocking everything from search engines